# Laptop instantly wakes up from suspend or goes into a suspend-loop (XPS 15 7590, Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: nvidia, suspend, power-management, 22.04, xps

Update: I noticed, that in some cases my Laptop when trying to suspend does not just unsuspend instantly, but instead gets stuck in a stuspend-unsuspend-suspend-...-loop. I have to force-shutdown my laptop in those cases. I tried the solution provided for a similar problem on Razer laptops (adding `button.lid_init_state=open` to the boot-options), but that did not work in my case.

Also: When I suspend via `sudo pm-suspend`, the suspension works and stays suspended, but I don't get a login-screen when unsuspending. I was also unable to find a way to tell Gnome/Ubuntu to use pm-suspend for suspension instead of whatever it does internally...

---

Original Post:

My Laptop (XPS 15 7590) always instantly comes back from hibernation and suspend. Even when the lid is closed this lights up the screen and my laptop becomes very hot when stored in my bag. This makes my laptop completely unusable as a laptop because it can not stay unplugged for extended amounts of time before running out of charge.

The problem started after upgrading to the nvidia-515 drivers. (Even though I have the nvidia-gpu disabled via `prime-select intel`; `nvidia-smi` tells me, that the GPU can't be reached) (nvidia-smi version: v515.43.04)

I already disabled the wakeup for all devices listed in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`. (Except PBTN, which is the Powerbutton)

It was not possible to disable two devices both called PXSX via `echo PXSX > /proc/acpi/wakeup`, so I disabled them completely via `echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/<sysfs node>/remove`. My laptop still wakes up instantly, but my WiFi stopped working...

I also tried

```
sudo systemctl enable nvidia-suspend.service
sudo systemctl enable nvidia-hibernate.service
sudo systemctl enable nvidia-resume.service
```

which returns `Failed to enable unit: Unit file nvidia-suspend.service does not exist.` etc.

The syslog mentions a wakeup caused by the NetworkManager (`NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1655725449.0352] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes`). I was unable to find any information on how one would go about fixing that. Disabling WiFi and Bluetooth changed nothing.
The syslog contains no other information about wakeups.

There are no external devices connected to my laptop.

Device: XPS 15 7590 (Dell)
OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 5.15.0-25-generic
DE: GNOME 42.0
CPU: Intel i7-9750H (12) @ 4.500GHz
GPU: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q

Edit:
I also followed [this guide](https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-close-lid-suspend/#:%7E:text=Make%20sure%20to%20enable%20suspend%20for%20lid%20close%20action&text=Go%20to%20System%20Settings%20and,Ubuntu%20by%20closing%20the%20lid.) and edited my `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to include the mentioned `HandleLidSwitch=suspend` and `HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend`. This also changed nothing.

Comment: What Is Your Current "Critical" Battery Percentage & Action?    
(as from the **dconf editor** values)

Comment: The NetworkManager output looks like a false lead to me. I think you're reading it backward: It's talking about the wifi chip being asleep, and waking it up that networking hardware *based upon the rest of the system already waking up*. While it it possible to set up wake-on-wifi on hardware that supports it, you would remember configuring that -- the default is 'disabled'.

Comment: is the power-on button on the side of the machine? what kind of "wake-on" events have you set this machine up with? -all- are disabled and inactive unless you set them up ;)

Comment: @ByronTaaka battery percent: 3%, action: 'suspend'

Comment: @user535733 Ok. thanks. I checked the BIOS and anything regarding Wake-on-LAN is disabled.

Comment: @Rinzwind The power-on button is next to the keyboard (on the inside). I did not explicitly enable any "wake-on" events. (Should be at the defaults set by Ubuntu). /proc/acpi/wakeup listed some as enabled and as I stated, I disabled all of them except for the power button. So it seems like it's not a hardware-device, that is causing the wake-up? But I have no idea where else it could come from. Syslog only mentions NetworkManager...

Comment: Damn I'm experiencing the same issue and I don't have a clue of what it could be..